# MailingCountry contact field in before insert trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext, address

I have to populate a Contact field programmatically according to the `MailingCountry` field in the before insert trigger so the contact is created properly. But I noticed that the field `MailingCountry` on Contact is populated in a weird way in the before trigger context; here's a sample trigger to reproduce the behaviour

```
trigger TR01_Contact on Contact (before insert, before update, after delete) {
    if(Trigger.IsBefore && Trigger.IsInsert)
    {
        for(Contact c : Trigger.new)
        {
            system.debug(JSON.serialize(c));
            system.debug(JSON.serialize(c.MailingCountry));
        }
    }
}
```

the output of this trigger is

```
contacts [{"attributes": {
"type": "Contact"
},
"Show_on_Account_Plan__c": false,
"IsDeleted": false,
"AccountId": "0011800000cLvVmAAK",
"Email": "nb@m.it",
"IsEmailBounced": false,
"DoNotCall": false,
"FirstName": "test",
"HasOptedOutOfEmail": false,
"HasOptedOutOfFax": false,
"SNPCAPIQ__Is_DB_USA_Data__c": false,
"CurrencyIsoCode": "USD",
"Salutation": "Mr.",
"pi__Needs_Score_Synced__c": false,
"OwnerId": "005f4000001LmWJAA0",
"MailingCountryCode": "IT",
"RecordTypeId": "012180000000YrGAAU",
"pi__pardot_hard_bounced__c": false,
"Contact_Summary_Ref__c": "a0318000008OUc8AAG",
"LastName": "test",
"Status__c": "Active",
"Prospecting_Stage__c": "New Contact",
"Opt_in__c": false
```

and

```
null
```

also MailingCountryCode is populated and if I go to the record page after the insertion I can see that MailingCountry is correctly displayed as "Italy"

I need a way to read MailingCountry or a way to retrieve the MailingCountry from the MailingCountryCode. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have enabeled 'State and Country/Territory Picklists' in your org use the below code to get country details.
**Please don't add inside for loop.**

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = User.Countrycode.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
Map<String,String> countryMap = new Map<String,String>();
for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
    System.debug(f.getLabel() +'::'+ f.getValue());
    countryMap.put(f.getValue(), f.getLabel());
}
```

You will get country code from `c.MailingCountryCode`.

Use `countryMap.get(c.MailingCountryCode)` to get country name.

Else you may need to used [Custom Metadata Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=5) or [Custom Setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm) to store country code and label accordingly and access this whenever as needed.